# Функция занимает всю память php

Tags: php

```
    $post = http_build_query(
        array(
          'id'=>$id,
          'domainid'=>$config['domain_id'],
          'name'=>$name,
          'meta'=>$meta,
          'html'=>$html,
          'active'=>$active,
          'session'=>$config['session'])
        );
```

Данная функция занимает всю память php, и скрипт не выполняется.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 130547741 bytes) in

Проблема в том что переменная html занимает 16кб, как можно решить подобную проблему?

Comment: а переменная `$config['session']` сколько занимает? А может все же проблема во всём скрипте? а не конкретно в этой переменной?

Comment: И что в контексте, может вы эту функцию в рекурсии вызываете и как раз на момент ее очередной отработки память и заканчиватся

Comment: если убираю переменную все мгновенно работает, остальные строки не больше 20 байт

Answer (score 1):

Если `$html` никак не сократить, то попробуйте:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Ещё вариант,

```
http_build_query([/* данные */], null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

И, наконец:

```
http_build_query([/* данные без ключа html */]).'&html='.urlencode($html);
```